# Azure service stops automatically

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

Currently I have published a Azure cloud service.
But the service stops often. I need to restart the service manually.
I cannot find any proper reason for such kind of behavior.

Can anyone help me, What should the reason ??

Thanks,
Rudresh

Comment: There could be many reasons for that. I would suggest putting some logging in your role's OnStop() method.

Comment: I have traced and this kind of msg received "Aborted 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportReplyChannelAcceptor+TransportReplyChannel/39086322'" but not understand what it means.

Comment: Is this a Web or Worker role?  Perhaps the application is throwing an unhandled exception, which causes the role to restart.  Do you see several restart events?  Can you successfully run the application locally (via the emulator)?

Comment: @mcollier, May be the application is throwing an unhandled exception. but when I test it in locally I failed to reproduce the issue. When I uploads the service in Azure service stops automatically after sometime and application shows the 502 error code.

Comment: @RudreshBhatt I am facing the same issue sir have you found any solution?